# How to connect Google Console Project with Google Analytics account

Tags: python, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-python-client, google-console-developer

I want to create Python project to get data from Google Analytics from a certain page.

I have created new project in Google Console (console.google.developers.com) and got my OAuth 2.0 credentians in JSON format. I'm loosely following this tutorial: [Python QuickStart](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/installed-py).

I already got redirected to OAuth and selected my account but the script is getting

> "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile".

Will adding access to my user in Google Analytics be enough?
And how to run this project from shell on a remote server? I will not have the ability to just open browser and select Google account in CLI...

Answer (score 1):

> "User does not have sufficient permissions for this profile".

The user you are authencating with does not have access to the google analytics account you are trying to access.   this would be the profile id that you are using in your code.

1. make sure that you are authencting your appliction using the same user you are using to log into google analytics
2. double check the profile id that you are using in your code.

Comment: Ok, got it. Can you try to answer the second part of the question? How would this work for CLI? I cannot expect cron to use browser to select a Google account. Any ideas?

Comment: you will have to open it once and save the refresh token to request a new access token.  IF this is an account you own personally you should consider using a service account instead